# C++ Program Returning Abort Trap

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to write a C++ that inputs `n` and then inputs `n` words. Then I input an `s` and then print out the `n` words with `s` removed. When I try to implement my program, my program says that there is an abort error. Does anyone know why? Thanks a lot.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    string words[100];

    cin >> n;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cin >> words[i];
    }

    string s; cin >> s;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        int n = words[i].find(s);
        words[i] = words[i].erase(n,n+s.length());
    }

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cout << words[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know why?

Comment: What do you think `n` is if `s` isn't found?

Comment: You also should not name 2 variables the same name. This makes the code harder to read.

Comment: @Pigeon01 No, `int n = words[i].find(s);`. Also, read the documentation of `string::erase` and check what the second argument is with the non-iterator overload.

Comment: I changed the name of the variable, but it doesn't fix the "Abort trap: 6" error I'm getting

Comment: @molbdnilo Ok, I will

Comment: Add `cout << n << endl;` inside the loop, between the declaration and the erasure,  and have a look at what it is.

Comment: It seems to be correct when I add that code.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the ```words[i] = words[i].erase(len,len+s.length());``` code, though I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: If `s` isn't found, `n` is negative, which causes undefined behaviour with `erase`. And the second argument is the number of characters to remove, not the "one past the end" index. Read all about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase).

Comment: @drescherjm Actually, that specific overload, which has no iterators as parameters, also does not return an iterator but `*this`, that is, the modified string. The assignment is redundant but harmless.

Comment: Should I add an if statement to only run if n is not equal to -1?

Comment: Here is my new code:

Comment: ```#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    string words[100];

    cin >> n;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cin >> words[i];
    }

    string s; cin >> s;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        int len = words[i].find(s);
        // cout << len << endl;
        if (len != -1) {
            words[i] = words[i].erase(len,len+s.length());
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cout << words[i] << endl;
    }
}```

Comment: It's still not correct though

Comment: Solved it. Thanks for all the help!